# How can i control the extrude size of a curve while creating it?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

i need to make a sightly smaller subdivission on my curve because i need to reach a part of the 3D enviroment without having to move the object, so i use extrude (pressing E) but the curve created is too long and the shape is lost.
Is there any way i can control the curve size while pressing E?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you are saying?

Comment: Couldn't you scale the curve you already have?

Comment: Well, yes, i can scale it, but i want to know if there's also an option to just make a curve (by pressing E) start from 0 rather than an already made curve

Comment: select the control point and using the transform->location panel you can place it manually where you need it

Comment: Can you make an answer with pictures? i think that's the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating a curve you have some control using the parameters on the tool bar (press **<kbd>T</kbd>** to make it visible) or revel the tool options bypressing **<kbd>F6</kbd>**

[image]

Once a Curve has been created it can be manipulated with precision using the Transform control panels. (Press **<kbd>N</kbd>** to make it visible)

[image]